# ¿Cómo sumar 1 en un array?

Tags: javascript, prompt

Tengo este código, el cual funciona, pero quiero sumarle *1* a los números que se introduzcan. ¿Cómo se hace esto?

Ejemplo: Si introduzco *1* al `prompt`, que este guarde el (número introducido en el `prompt`, pero sumando *1*.

```
let cantidad = prompt("¿Cuántos números vas a imprimir?");
let numeros = [];
for (var i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
    numeros[i] = [prompt("numero" + (i+1))];
}
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que el bucle se ejecute una vez más que el número introducido? En ese caso, puedes sumarle 1 a "cantidad" después de la primera línea añadiendo "cantidad++;".

Answer (score 0):

pues crea una variable la cual se llama numero;

```
var numero=0;
```

luego ya dentro de tu ciclo for pones esto:

```
numero="leer numero introducido por el usuario";
numero=numero+1;
```

luego guardas el valor de numero en la posicion del arreglo, como lo haces en tu ciclo. y ya con eso

Answer (score 0):

Se convierte el `prompt` a número con un `+` a la izquierda:

```
+prompt("número")
```

Luego se le agrega `1+` a la izquierda para sumar `1`:

```
1+ +prompt("número")
```

Código completo:

```js
let cantidad = prompt("¿Cuántos números vas a imprimir?")
let números = []
for (var i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
    números[i] = 1+ +prompt("número")
}
console.log(...números)
```